# Mapping Mongo id field with Google Gson

Tags: java, gson

I'm reading a Document from MongoDB which contains its unique identifier:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5526888bd3d56a86cea8ea12"),
    "name" : "user1"
}
```

I'd like to map that with a java class

```
public class Mapper {
    Object _id;
    String name;
}
```

As a result of my fromJson execution:

```
Mapper m = gson.fromJson(string, Mapper.class);
```

...the value stored in the _id field is `{$oid=5526888bd3d56a86cea8ea12}`. I'd like to store the id String in it. (e.g. `"5526888bd3d56a86cea8ea12"`)

Can Gson do it for me automatically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a custom adapter to tell the parser that you only want to grab the value between parenthesis and quotes in the string value (note that id is now a String in your `Mapper` class). The regex can be changed to match the ids requirements that are generated.

```
class MapperAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Mapper> {

    private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(\"([a-zA-Z\\d]+)\"\\)");

    @Override
    public Mapper deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jObj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        String id = jObj.get("_id").getAsString();
        String name = jObj.get("name").getAsString();

        Matcher m = p.matcher(id);
        if(!m.find()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The id should be within parenthesis and quotes.");
        }
        return new Mapper(m.group(1), name);
    }
}
```

and you register it in your parser:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Mapper.class, new MapperAdapter()).create();
Mapper m = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Mapper.class);
```

This yield the output:

```
Mapper{id=5526888bd3d56a86cea8ea12, name=user1}
```