# Regular expression to parse id

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to parse the id of a record in MongoDB:

```
{"$oid":"5527b117d3d511091e1735e2"}
```

I'm trying with the following one but it fails:

```
 private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\"([a-zA-Z\\d]+)\"\\}");

 Matcher m = p.matcher("{\"$oid\":\"5527b117d3d511091e1735e2\"}");
 if(!m.find()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The id should be within parenthesis and quotes.");
 }
```

Any help ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Tichodroma The OP already uses a JSON parser, although I'm not sure what he's trying to achieve here. I answered [his](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541413/mapping-mongo-id-field-with-google-gson) question yesterday. To the OP: what do you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the key part also in the regex or just `"\\{\"([a-zA-Z\\d$]+)\":"` because  `[a-zA-Z\\d]+` won't match the inbetween `:`  and there isn't a closing curly brace immediately following the key part.

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\"([a-zA-Z\\d$]+)\":\"([^\"]*)\"\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("{\"$oid\":\"5527b117d3d511091e1735e2\"}");
if(m.find())
{
    System.out.println("Key : " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Value : " + m.group(2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Key : $oid
Value : 5527b117d3d511091e1735e2
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
    String id = str.replaceAll(".*\"(\\w+)\"}", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON parser:

```
String j = "{\"$oid\":\"5527b117d3d511091e1735e2\"}";

JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
JSONObject o = (JSONObject) p.parse(j);
System.out.println(o.get("$oid"));
```

Output:

```
5527b117d3d511091e1735e2
```

JSON library used:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```